# Changing Wordpress website to html-made site

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, html

I made a website for a customer using HTML, CSS and JavaScript. They had an existing site that they wanted to take down and put my new one up in its place and keep the same domain name. When I went to host it I then learned that their original website was created using WordPress. I want to know is there anyway I can host the new site that was created using HTML in place of the WordPress one.

Comment: Just remove all wordpress files and upload your files instead.

Comment: If you have FTP access you should be able to just delete (with backup) the entire `wwwroot` folder and place your HTML there.

Comment: You may want to backup the old files first. Just in case...

Comment: Who upvoted this?

Answer (score 0):

Using your FTP client, connect to the production server and make a backup of the existing files (this is a good routine to get into, as you never know when a client may need something from the old site). You'll also want to connect to the MySQL database (credentials can be found in the site's wp-config.php file) and back that up as well, as that holds all of the actual site content.

Once you've prepared the backup, you can remove the files currently living in the web root and replace them with your static HTML site.

Alternatively, if you're able to specify an alternate web root, you might consider uploading your site into a new directory adjacent to the current web root directory, then point the web server to that directory instead. This approach reduces the risk of downtime and gives you an easy rollback path should you ever need to revert to the WordPress-based site.

Answer (score 0):

You don't sound like you have much experience with that so you better make a test folder and test your new website on the server first. Then if everything is OK proceed to saving and removing of the WordPress files and folders and uploading of your files. During this procedure you may put temporary webpage that will inform visitors. It's a good idea to have a htaccess file to handle redirects. After you remove old pages you'll have a lot 404s so it will be good idea to redirect those to the index, in case old and new pages' URLs don't match.